# Google OAuth2 Fails saying invalid_client

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I get an error saying `invalid_client` while using the google oauth2 with django-social-auth

[image]

Here is my google console page

```
Project ID:  gect-coderpool  Project Number:  258021043059
```

[image]

Finally the following are the credentials in my settings.py

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID      = '258021043059.apps.googleusercontent.com'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET  = '***'
```

I have many applications running on django-social-auth,which have similar settings and they still continue to work like a charm(only difference is that they are on heroku, and this is localhost).

I would like to point out that those applications were created using the old google console and this one via the new one.

What am I missing?

```
Django == 1.3.1
django_social_auth == 0.7.25
```

Comment: its a bug...i too face same problem

Comment: whats is like a 3 day long bug ?hope they fix it asap

Comment: Had a similar issue a while ago when testing the new panel, regenerating the keys fixed it on one project, on another I had to switch to the old panel.

Comment: still no good.tried both.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE : its working now :) just generate new id and secret ;)